# Wait for all promises to resolve before updating state and redirect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, promise, react-hooks, firebase-storage

The `.then()` in my code below is triggered after one image is uploaded. At that time it is too early to update my state variable and make a redirect. I should wait for all files to be uploaded before proceeding. Can someone point me in a direction to accomplish this?

```
 const storageRef = app.storage()
 const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
 const [data, setData] = React.useState()

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
      storageRef
        .ref(`${data.firebaseRef}/${file.id}`)
        .put(file)
        .then(() => {
          // Only if all files are uploaded to firebase then I need to do something
        })
    })
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Promise.all()` to wait for all promises to resolve before doing something else:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  Promise.all(files.map(file =>
    storageRef
      .ref(`${data.firebaseRef}/${file.id}`)
      .put(file)
  )).then(() => {
    // Only if all files are uploaded to firebase then I need to do something
  })
}
```

Comment: Hey @Ori, this is not working for me. `.then()` gets invoked immediately

Comment: I had it structured wrong, your answer works as expected. Thanks!